# Issues when installing Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: installation, software-center, adobe, canonical, adobe-acrobat

Actually I'm trying to install the acro reader on my 13.10 Ubuntu desktop.
I have activated the Canonical repositoy (already availble in my software packages) by ticking the checkbox but when opening the Ubuntu Software Center and pointing to Canonical Partners I can't see the Acrobat Reader package but only 5 packages available:

- Client for skype VOIP and instant messaging service.
- GTK+ control panel for Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11.
- Client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service -binary files.
- KDE control panel Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11.
- Adobe Flash Player plugin version 11.

I've already updated my packages sources through `sudo apt-get install update` and even tried to install it from terminal `sudo apt-get install acroread` but I got message showing no packages found.

So am I missing some step around this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
BR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked, i can't find it either anymore actually, no error on your end. Might have been removed (never know with third party packages)

You can get it from [adobes website](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) though.

By default it offers a *.bin, but you can get a *.deb by clicking on "Do you have a different language or operating system?" and choose Linux > Language > .deb

Once this is downloaded, click it and it should open in Ubuntus Software Center, and can be installed/managed in there like normal.

Comment: Thanks @canofcolliders, I'm actually aware with the proposed alternative. But it makes things clearer as you checked on your side.